# Paypal Chained Payment vs multiple Simple Payments

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am interested in implementing a system requiring something very similar to the Paypal Chained payment system. In this system, a payer pays a payee (or multiple payees) through a middleman (the owner of the site), who can take a cut of the payment. Paypal executes all these payments simultaneously, or has an option to allow delayed payments also.

[image: a busy cat]

However, the chained payment structure does not appear to be yet supported on the new REST APIs implemented by Paypal. I would rather not implement a new site with legacy APIs. However, it seems to me that this system could be recreated by simply combining multiple simple payments. For example, the payee pays you (the website owner), and then the website automatically pays the payee while taking a cut, all using simple payments (payer to payee).

Is there any conceivable disadvantage to this system? Even something such as the legal status of holding money vs. just allowing it to all be handled through Paypal?

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as calling them legacy API's, and I would recommend sticking with them for awhile anyway.  The REST API is something they launched just to provide an answer to what Stripe was doing, basically.  It's not nearly as mature as the "classic" API, and the classic API isn't going anywhere for a long while.  LOTS of live applications using it, of course, and until REST catches up they can't force people to change because it's not possible without the same functionality.  I myself have been sticking with classic and don't plan on switching any time soon.

Comment: OK thanks! Good to hear that the classic API will be with us for a while. I'm so used to seeing older technologies being marginalized after new releases that I usually become somewhat allergic to using anything but the newest releases. Just out of curiosity can you speak to the question of the difference between the Chained and multiple Single payment structures? Is Chained somehow better? I guess it has to be or they wouldn't have created it in the first place..

Comment: Really just a matter of your application model and what might work best for you.  The fees could be part of it, too.  If I remember correctly, fees in a split payment are split up (depending on who you set the feespayer to) where-as single payments over and over again would be charged each time.

Comment: Aha! I completely forgot about Paypal fees. That would definitely be a consideration in the comparison of these methods. Thank you.